# UITableView allow multi selection when select cell more than one cell selected

Tags: swift3, ios10

I have UITableView allow multi selection for the user to select the languages he speaks when select cell and scroll down in the table other cells selected.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:  IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell:UITableViewCell!
   cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "language",for: indexPath)
   cell?.textLabel?.text = languageValues[indexPath.row]
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
       cell.accessoryType = .none
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark     
 }
```

[gif explain the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70jtz.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that cells get cached and reused.  This means that they are a bad place to store state information.

I suggest that your `languageValues` array should contain objects where each object has a name string and a selected boolean.  When someone selects or deselects a cell, change the boolean to match and reload data for the affected cell (or the table).

That way only `cellForRowAt indexPath` will change the `accessoryType` value.